# Receiving both image and JSON in multipart response with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, cxf, multipart

I try to rebuild the server's response in order to store the received contents (Images and JSON).
The code of the server is like that of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451073/returning-both-image-and-json-in-multipart-response-with-jersey?newreg=5d10c1e7ec71461582932f5cd3f628fa)
I changed the server to return TXT files, i get the folowing on the client.

```
        Response response = client.post(body);
        logger.info("content :" + response.readEntity(String.class));


--Boundary_9_2112219484_1499871974802
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="file1.txt"

Content of file 1
--Boundary_9_2112219484_1499871974802
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="file2.txt"

Content of file 2
--Boundary_9_2112219484_1499871974802--
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question please. Do you mean to say, you want to return multiple part response as provider in link using Cxf as well

Answer (score 0):

I would instead try to base 64 encode the image and then return it as a string in the JSON without any problems.